# Modeling particles moving through a chamber

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-modeling

Consider the following phenomenon.

Particles each traveling with speed $v_i$ metres per second enter a chamber at a rate of $r$ particles per second.

Upon entering the chamber, each particle begins to reduce its speed from $v_i$ to $v_f$.  Each particle then exits the chamber.

If I look at an individual particle entering the chamber at time $0$, it is travelling $Ce^{-At}$ metres per second after $t$ seconds.  The constants $C$ and $A$ are the same for every particle.

I let this process run for some time.  Is there an expression $n(v,t)$ describing the number of particles in the chamber which are travelling at speed $v_i \leq v \leq v_f$ at time $t > 0$?

Comment: Based on your description, it would seem that $v(0)=v_i = C$ and that the particle exists after a time $T$ such that $v(T)=v_f=v_i e^{-AT}$. Is this valid?

Comment: Please confirm (or deny) that "expression $n(v,t)$" means "an expression in terms of $v$ and $t$".

Comment: Yes these are all correct observations.

Comment: If $v$ is only one constant, then the number of particle would be either 1 (at _very_ specific times) or 0 (other times) at any given time. Do you mean "for each $v$" or "the total number of particles in the chamber in a given time"?

Comment: This is a valid point, if we've been through at least $T$ seconds, where $T$ represents the time it takes for one particle to traverse the entire chamber.  Perhaps my question is ill-posed.

Comment: I guess what the form of an answer should be is this:  at any given moment, there are a certain number of particles in the system, and their speeds all fall evenly on an exponential curve $v(x)$, where $x$ is the distance from the entrance of the chamber and we assume that the chamber is a line.

Comment: @OpenSeason I'll assume the latter anyway. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the statement

> If I look at an individual particle entering the chamber at time $0$, it is travelling $Ce^{−At}$ metres per second after $t$ seconds. The constants $C$ and $A$ are the same for every particle.

If $t=0$, the speed would be $C\cdot e^{−A*0}=C\cdot e^0=C$. Therefore, $v_i=C$ (Thanks @Semiclassical for pointing this out before). So the speed of a particle which entered the chamber at time $0$ after $t$ seconds is

### $v_i\cdot e^{−At}$

Let $t_c$ be the time required for a particle to traverse the chamber. We obtain

### $v_f=v_ie^{-A\cdot t_c}$

### $\rightarrow\frac{v_f}{v_i}=e^{-A\cdot t_c}$

### $\rightarrow\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}=-A\cdot t_c$

### $\Rightarrow-\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A=t_c$

At this point, let me make a few assumptions (let me know if any is wrong):

1. The question is "How many particles are in the chamber at a given time?"
2. The first particle enters at $t=0$
3. A particle which is exactly at the entrance of the chamber is considered inside the chamber (thus at $t=0$ there is $1$ particle in the chamber)
4. A particle is no longer considered inside the chamber as soon as its speed reaches $v_f$

Consider that the rate of particle entrance is $r\cdot s^{-1}$. In other words, a particle enters every $\frac1{r\cdot s^{-1}}=\frac1r\text{ }s$. Therefore, the number of particles which have entered the chamber before or at time $t$ is

### $\lfloor\frac tr\rfloor+1$

Also consider that, starting at $t=t_c=-\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A$ (i.e. when the first particle exits), particles start exiting the chamber every $\frac1r\text{ }s$. Therefore, the number of particles which have exited the chamber before or at time $t\ge-\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A$ is

### $\lfloor\frac{t-(-\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A)}r\rfloor+1$

### $=\lfloor\frac{t+\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A}r\rfloor+1$

Therefore, at a given time $t\ge-\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A$, the number of particles which have entered the chamber and still is in the chamber is

### $\lfloor\frac tr\rfloor+1-(\lfloor\frac{t+\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A}r\rfloor+1)$

### $=\lfloor\frac tr\rfloor+1-\lfloor\frac{t+\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A}r\rfloor-1$

### $=\lfloor\frac tr\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{t+\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A}r\rfloor$

Therefore, considering the case that $t\lt-\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A$, the formula of the number of particles in the chamber at any given point is

## $n(t)=\begin{cases}\lfloor\frac tr\rfloor+1\text{, if }t\lt-\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A\\\lfloor\frac tr\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{t+\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A}r\rfloor\text{, if }t\ge-\frac{\ln\frac{v_f}{v_i}}A\end{cases}$